# Nominative vs Accusative Cases: Why is it "Das ist ein Kaffee" and not "Das ist einen Kaffee"?

Tags: grammatical-case, verb-usage

I'm taking a German A1 course and have started learning about the nominative and accusative cases.

This is the example they gave...[image]

The big takeaway I got is that if the noun is the direct object (the verb is taking an action on it) and the noun is masculine, then you need to change ein to einen and der to den.

But here is my confusion... in the sentence "Das ist ein Kaffee" isn't sein ("ist" in this case) a verb taking an action on the coffee? Thus shouldn't it be "Das ist einen Kaffee"?